# How to show an ellipses (...) at the end of the text in a textarea?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox, windows-phone

[image]

How i can add an ellipses (...) to end of the text in a textbox if there is no space to show the remain text or sentence in WP8 using C#?

Comment: The word that you are searching is 'ellipsis': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the desired text string and the maximum characters length of your text-box, use this extension method to solve it:

```
public static string TruncateAtWord(this string input, int length)
{
    if (input == null || input.Length < length)
        return input;

    int iNextSpace = input.LastIndexOf(" ", length);

    return string.Format("{0}...", input.Substring(0, (iNextSpace > 0) ? iNextSpace : length).Trim());
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var ellipsisedString = "this is a very long string and I want to cut it with ellipsis!".TruncateAtWord(25);
```

**Result:**

"this is a very long..."

Comment: This answer is not really correct because it fails when the user interface is adjusted (i.e. the font is adjusted). The only real way to solve this problem is on the user interface side (i.e `TextTrimming`): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to the other two solutions, you could use TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" in the XAML, it just depends on whether you want to limit the string to a certain number of characaters or let the trimming occur based on textbox size.

Comment: This is not just an "alternative" answer, but how it should really be done.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to truncate strings when I needed some simple text logging. Might be an inspiration.

```
public static string Truncate(this string yourString, int maxLength)
{
    return yourString.Substring(0, Math.Min(maxLength, yourString.Length));
}
```

Reviewing Yair Nevet's answer I find his take on the problem more complete. You can use the code above similarly to his answer:

```
string yourString = "Your long text goes here".Truncate(10);
```